# How to delete the row with missing character values using SAS

Tags: sas, character, row

I have a data set like this:

```
id     type       time
70657  23E  Nov  4 2002 12:00AM
61651  12R  
11603  DQ2  
45819       Jul 23 2013 12:00AM
       732  Mar  4 2011 12:00AM
22810  231
```

I want to do two things with missing values. 
The first thing is how to remove the rows if the values of the variable time is " ".

desired output1

```
id     type       time
70657  23E  Nov  4 2002 12:00AM 
45819       Jul 23 2013 12:00AM
       732  Mar  4 2011 12:00AM
```

The second thing is to remove the rows if there is any missing values.

desired output2

```
id     type       time
70657  23E  Nov  4 2002 12:00AM
```

SAS code:

```
data character;
  length id type time $ 24;
  input id $ 1-5 type $ 8-10 time $ 13-31;
cards;
70657  23E  Nov  4 2002 12:00AM
61651  12R  
11603  DQ2  
45819       Jul 23 2013 12:00AM
       732  Mar  4 2011 12:00AM
22810  231
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `proc sql`.  Something like:

```
proc sql;
    create table newchar as
        select *
        from character
        where id is not null and type is not null and time is not null;
quit;
```

Comment: this works, but my real data is more than 10000 rows, I run this sql in my data, it produce double rows up to 20000 rows.What happen here?

Comment: @LuYu . . . I had the wrong logic.  It was returning rows that had a `null` value in some column, rather than no `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

The SAS alternative.

```
DATA WANT;
    SET CHARACTER (WHERE = (TIME ~= "" AND TYPE ~= "" AND ID ~= ""));
RUN;
```